# subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_N^k$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, exponential-sum

Let $S$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_N^k$, and $S^{\perp} = \{t | t \in \mathbb{Z}_N^k,\,\mbox{and}\,\forall s \in S,\, t\cdot s = 0\}$, here the dot product is defined as $t\cdot s = \sum_{i=1}^k t_is_i \mod N$. Is it possible to prove that for $y \notin S^\perp$, $$\sum_{s\in S}e^{2\pi i s\cdot y/N} = 0 $$

Here is my proof for the case of $k=1$. Since $S$ is a cyclic group, let $g$ be a generator of $S$, then $S = \{0, g, 2g, 3g, ... (|S|-1)g\}$, then the summation becomes the sum of a geometric sequence and leads to $0$ easily. But for $k > 1$, $S$ is not always cyclic, then my logic won't work any more.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very basic result on character sums over a finite abelian group (see my answer for a standard argument). Such sums are encountered in number theory and are used as a tool in studying equations over finite fields. They are also a (simple) special case of characters of finite groups that you encounter when studying representation theory. In other words, the topic is well connected to other parts of algebra & number theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is a standard fact.

Consider the function
$$
\chi_y:S\to\Bbb{C}^*, s\mapsto e^{2\pi i\,s\cdot y/N}.
$$
Because $(s+s')\cdot y= s\cdot y+s'\cdot t$ (as elements of $\Bbb{Z}_N$) for all $s,s'\in S$ we see that $\chi_y$ is a homomorphism of groups: $\chi_y(s+s')=\chi_y(s)\chi_y(s')$.

The assumption that $y\notin S^\perp$ implies that there exists an element $s_0\in S$ such that $\chi_y(s_0)\neq1$. This is because $\chi_y(s)=1$ if and only if $s\cdot y\equiv0\pmod N$. Let us fix such an element $s_0\in S$.

Next we can consider your sum
$$
\Sigma(y):=\sum_{s\in S}\chi_y(s).
$$
Because $S$ is a group $s+s_0$ ranges over the elements of $S$ while $s$ does. 
In other words, if we write $s=s'+s_0$ and let $s'$ range over $S$, we get all the elements $s\in S$ exactly once. Utilizing this
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma(y)&=\sum_{s\in S}\chi_y(s)\\
&=\sum_{s'\in S}\chi_y(s'+s_0)\\
&=\sum_{s'\in S}\chi_y(s')\chi_y(s_0)\\
&=\chi_y(s_0)\left(\sum_{s'\in S}\chi_y(s')\right)\\
&=\chi_y(s_0)\Sigma(y).
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
(\chi_y(s_0)-1)\Sigma(y)=0.
$$
Here $\chi_y(s_0)-1\neq0$, so we can conclude that $\Sigma(y)=0$.

Comment: Alternatively you can let $H$ be the kernel of $\chi_y$. Then $\chi_y$ takes all its values $|H|$ times. So you get simply $|H|$ times the geometric sum that you got in the cyclic case. $|H|\cdot0=0$.